# Flip View error - accessing unknown getter method

Tags: iphone

I am having a view called `NView` on which I am having a design button clicking on which I want another view `DView` in flipview, but it's not working. Below is my code. I got an error called `accessing unknown getter method`:

```
NSLog(@"yuppii");
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:([NView superview] ? UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft : UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight)
                       forView: DView cache:YES];
```

Comment: Read the error message. If still unsure, show it here.

Comment: [NView superview] here is the prob . what is NView is it NSView

Comment: NView is just a name of UIView....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you aren't using a container view as the transition view. Refer to the documentation on setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:

```
If you want to change the appearance of a view during a transition—for example, flip from one view to another—then use a container view, an instance of UIView, as follows:

   1. Begin an animation block.
   2. Set the transition on the container view.
   3. Remove the subview from the container view.
   4. Add the new subview to the container view.
   5. Commit the animation block.
```

Try using self.view.superview in the animation transition view of the showMoreInfo:

The reason the showLessInfo: method works is you are using a container view.

or use this way-may be helped u......

CustomViewController *vc = [[CustomViewController alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController" bundle:nil];

vc.delegate = self;

// The magic statement. This will flip from right to left.
// present the modal view controller then when you dismissModalViewController
// it will transition flip from left to right. Simple and elegant.

vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

[vc release];